# Places API Nearby Search behavior, queries sometimes return different data

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

When I hit the same parameters several times, the results sometimes differ even if they are made at the same time.

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.18405997072579,18.12902221700711&radius=50000&keyword=sprzedaż%20pelletu&rankby=prominence&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

returned data:
First try

```json
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 51.4537103,
                    "lng": 17.9860007
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 51.45494492989273,
                        "lng": 17.98741417989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 51.45224527010728,
                        "lng": 17.98471452010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "Pelet D.G. - Producent Pelletu",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 1080,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108531728908816388599\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AWU5eFg0Jr1q94CKD-X4zcQjLzqKCLRzXkJdBVnbcbYxOGXj-DZuYv3ArpQDiYODT_FudoZUsMZZZVc7YR_7DH3WNLqUqphekvFCPiowzuHSQ1ejVGYiqy9LVpy6vyWyHu0yZoUH-mf2O02Y594kdu3ZozkJitgZTZYm-787hKMhHUy105ct",
                    "width": 1080
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJkTScEuuWGkcRsozUTO_9A-A",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "FX3P+FC Zajączki",
                "global_code": "9F3VFX3P+FC"
            },
            "rating": 4.9,
            "reference": "ChIJkTScEuuWGkcRsozUTO_9A-A",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "general_contractor",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 14,
            "vicinity": "Zajączki 65A"
        },
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 51.1198472,
                    "lng": 18.3473912
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 51.12121377989271,
                        "lng": 18.34856042989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 51.11851412010727,
                        "lng": 18.34586077010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "FERNANDO PELLET",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 304,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112336568147323955037\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AWU5eFgVj5FDQga9r8L9qmLqLCqA2ljvO2BPx3LjqMG2AkQLbdy1Drnis-qg5nQ4Hv_v08DD8DJIRLtP3RVVX-XfIKiUTEAs3zFyHgSK-522a6NL6AKF28JryMtxfQwr_uMKeiX14P68jQMd6mzrW8XCorvBF6RNog88WMycGNI6Q3lvKcwD",
                    "width": 540
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJV8idBDN9EEcRjQKJVFPwQzA",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "489W+WX Uszyce",
                "global_code": "9F3W489W+WX"
            },
            "rating": 4.7,
            "reference": "ChIJV8idBDN9EEcRjQKJVFPwQzA",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "general_contractor",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 15,
            "vicinity": "Uszyce 148"
        },
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 51.01748689999999,
                    "lng": 18.0529209
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 51.01873167989272,
                        "lng": 18.05400282989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 51.01603202010728,
                        "lng": 18.05130317010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "Hurtowa i detaliczna sprzedaż pelletu",
            "place_id": "ChIJ95MubZVoEEcRbC9fDNHUBkQ",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "2383+X5 Wołczyn",
                "global_code": "9F3W2383+X5"
            },
            "rating": 0,
            "reference": "ChIJ95MubZVoEEcRbC9fDNHUBkQ",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 0,
            "vicinity": "Kluczborska 33, Wołczyn"
        },
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 50.8932429,
                    "lng": 18.7357948
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 50.89455772989272,
                        "lng": 18.73710272989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 50.89185807010728,
                        "lng": 18.73440307010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "PELLET WRONA | SMART TRADE PATRYCJUSZ WRONA",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 2016,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108562417225523917052\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AWU5eFjUigUFF9G-8U515cVElw5oEBwFaEyo0vgxUJdNGDDKrq6ySOvaKGHgxt4pqyd0mF_QMI8XCa0VknhUcHBc7z6w9KYkaVfhfJ5qTTt0Q7k8jPYgCe65EcpSePsOIXmJ6vfBw3PkkFzF93SGXmaYPCvuHKxGQrtyVB29A31sZq-sjYXA",
                    "width": 1504
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJCW47QbOVEEcRGGDo9X2vko0",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "VPVP+78 Cyganka",
                "global_code": "9F2WVPVP+78"
            },
            "rating": 4.7,
            "reference": "ChIJCW47QbOVEEcRGGDo9X2vko0",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "general_contractor",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 16,
            "vicinity": "Cyganka 5"
        },
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 51.5910247,
                    "lng": 18.7019331
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 51.59232572989272,
                        "lng": 18.70332497989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 51.58962607010727,
                        "lng": 18.70062532010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "Szymonik Marianna.Skład opału, pellet, sprzedaż rowerów",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 2232,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117863682179893725381\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AWU5eFjv8LnCReQlbjUACh7bOXuK2IfBW3m-60UpgR1mqOtR0BkVbmlxz5Rk4jM9N4HqDvISm3xr7BMKWgGEShmvmIZqhItJRBk5tbqa8DqiaoRZOtuIWTBRs_cjrkKSB6aGLZUbHHbQAl1MrjsZ1TQCtq_7FXyJOpHZm7xAq2prQrEw9rbt",
                    "width": 3268
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJlXuXU5_1GkcRTIECzP120w4",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "HPR2+CQ Sieradz",
                "global_code": "9F3WHPR2+CQ"
            },
            "rating": 4.5,
            "reference": "ChIJlXuXU5_1GkcRTIECzP120w4",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "bicycle_store",
                "general_contractor",
                "store",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 11,
            "vicinity": "Władysława Reymonta 66A, Sieradz"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

One of the next attempts

```json
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 50.7779965,
                    "lng": 18.7630752
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 50.77928837989272,
                        "lng": 18.76443117989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 50.77658872010728,
                        "lng": 18.76173152010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "PELL-DREW Adam Łebek produkcja pelletu",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 4640,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105980342792137550587\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AWU5eFiSF8MncpR09aZ3TdT65pjN-4nGsJXQ7oA9PYBGIc7hL15XrtQ_HqY2xWuAcZvh-Rb34y1UzruuZ9ZezcA43Xzhj3UMWC0Hcu0Gc4XTkgAPZBHDCtayE1xpF4re12xxieMAZ2NJf0OVyloFroghOzJhociSnlLz5K9c40Bgq1EY64VC",
                    "width": 3472
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJn28GbO_BEEcRxj0apz2DaKM",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "QQH7+66 Lisów",
                "global_code": "9F2WQQH7+66"
            },
            "rating": 0,
            "reference": "ChIJn28GbO_BEEcRxj0apz2DaKM",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "general_contractor",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 0,
            "vicinity": "Łebki 18"
        },
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 51.4537103,
                    "lng": 17.9860007
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 51.45494492989273,
                        "lng": 17.98741417989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 51.45224527010728,
                        "lng": 17.98471452010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "Pelet D.G. - Producent Pelletu",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 1080,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108531728908816388599\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AWU5eFi7aa-RyrbilzNJxWIQAB6nNB6D6R3TbEglk3UZCgpP89XiZyT6QtiBLXofnuuQHkcGHj3XacCkCqyUuMWtTgUOB79Jh7M2mG-N9_hoGDLZoYvZn_M_TuSB4jxnQ3U1UIRs9QbEAevCxZ5VdOAtfZJ7ronkT_pcIkqrzixfp3Qubchp",
                    "width": 1080
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJkTScEuuWGkcRsozUTO_9A-A",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "FX3P+FC Zajączki",
                "global_code": "9F3VFX3P+FC"
            },
            "rating": 4.9,
            "reference": "ChIJkTScEuuWGkcRsozUTO_9A-A",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "general_contractor",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 14,
            "vicinity": "Zajączki 65A"
        },
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 51.1198472,
                    "lng": 18.3473912
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 51.12121377989271,
                        "lng": 18.34856042989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 51.11851412010727,
                        "lng": 18.34586077010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "FERNANDO PELLET",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 304,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112336568147323955037\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AWU5eFh_QSzS10JRavkRnB4ttnPuVTyMX7EAxIYJdjZ5oDq5bGGDYVh2tan7HSlA2PzZMLVHNr-YFiiFQwFFeVOtbCQEUEdo9eSW1WMQvwCpoPqp49m5S2fRdzGYY3Wz_FZD93ltCRNuzQOk9USwjxjlkAlyqdHd-go1EQBZA185RoMDJ-xY",
                    "width": 540
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJV8idBDN9EEcRjQKJVFPwQzA",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "489W+WX Uszyce",
                "global_code": "9F3W489W+WX"
            },
            "rating": 4.7,
            "reference": "ChIJV8idBDN9EEcRjQKJVFPwQzA",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "general_contractor",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 15,
            "vicinity": "Uszyce 148"
        },
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 51.01748689999999,
                    "lng": 18.0529209
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 51.01873167989272,
                        "lng": 18.05400282989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 51.01603202010728,
                        "lng": 18.05130317010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "Hurtowa i detaliczna sprzedaż pelletu",
            "place_id": "ChIJ95MubZVoEEcRbC9fDNHUBkQ",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "2383+X5 Wołczyn",
                "global_code": "9F3W2383+X5"
            },
            "rating": 0,
            "reference": "ChIJ95MubZVoEEcRbC9fDNHUBkQ",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 0,
            "vicinity": "Kluczborska 33, Wołczyn"
        },
        {
            "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 50.8932429,
                    "lng": 18.7357948
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 50.89455772989272,
                        "lng": 18.73710272989272
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 50.89185807010728,
                        "lng": 18.73440307010728
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
            "icon_background_color": "#7B9EB0",
            "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
            "name": "PELLET WRONA | SMART TRADE PATRYCJUSZ WRONA",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 2016,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108562417225523917052\">A Google User</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "AWU5eFjKYjvKG17JWrflO93XBl7jaQx2VCSATdnZ9TOXntM3dzl9r50fitixd3kSEoCiJsm2N8WkyM2mbZ-9sOhUeDbM0zMnM-2bAH-iqOi-1WtKu7JnRHSHaDiFHHEuVQC61eU13o1dVe1x905nngDAW2Ggf24SxxTZVZLpKLcEPbj8KFOK",
                    "width": 1504
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJCW47QbOVEEcRGGDo9X2vko0",
            "plus_code": {
                "compound_code": "VPVP+78 Cyganka",
                "global_code": "9F2WVPVP+78"
            },
            "rating": 4.7,
            "reference": "ChIJCW47QbOVEEcRGGDo9X2vko0",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "general_contractor",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "user_ratings_total": 16,
            "vicinity": "Cyganka 5"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

All this data is from one Minutes.

the company "PELL-DREW Adam Łebek produkcja pelletu" is displayed in 1st place or is not included in the results at all

Api Docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby?hl=en

I'm trying to make a report from this data
and repeating it several times makes it not so reliable.

should I write a ticket with this error or is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using rankby prominence, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#:%7E:text=Possible%20values%20are%3A-,prominence,-(default).%20This%20option) specifically says that,

> *Prominence can be affected by a place's ranking in Google's index, global popularity, and other factors.*

Since there are a lot of factors affecting the results, it's kinda expected if the ranking/results itself are different sometimes. But you can still file a bug if you want to make sure if this is Working as Intended: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

But as far as I know, **[Places Web Service Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/faq#why_are_some_nearby_places_not_returned)** also addressed the question "**Why are some nearby places not returned?**" as to which the documentation answers:

> *By default, the Places API sorts results by `prominence` within the supplied `radius`. A [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) request can return up to 60 results, split across three pages. If a place ranks 22nd in `prominence`, it will appear on the second page of results which you can access through [paging](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging). If a place ranks greater than 60th in `prominence` it will not be included in the search result, even if it is closer to the center of your search.*
>
> *You can sort your results by `distance` instead of `prominence` by setting the `rankby` parameter in your query to `distance` and omitting the `radius` parameter. Relevance will be ignored and places will be returned in order of distance from `location`.*

I did some tests on both the parameter `rankby=prominence` and `rankby=distance` (Removing the `radius` parameter) without the keyword and found that the "**Pelet D.G. - Producent Pelletu**" is not in the first 20 results.

Sample Requests:

- With `rankby=prominence`: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.18405997072579,18.12902221700711&radius=5000&rankby=prominence&key=API_KEY`
- With `rankby=distance`: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.18405997072579,18.12902221700711&rankby=distance&key=API_KEY`

One thing I can conclude here is that the the company "**Pelet D.G. - Producent Pelletu**" is not "prominent" in the Google ranking index (at times).

What you can do to fix the inconsistent results is just to use `rankby=distance` and remove the `radius` parameter.

- Example: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.18405997072579,18.12902221700711&keyword=sprzeda%C5%BC%20pelletu&rankby=distance&key=API_KEY`

With this, it seems to be returning a more consistent results:

```
{
   "html_attributions":[
      
   ],
   "results":[
      {
         "business_status":"OPERATIONAL",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":51.1198472,
               "lng":18.3473912
            },
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":51.12121377989271,
                  "lng":18.34856042989272
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":51.11851412010727,
                  "lng":18.34586077010728
               }
            }
         },
         "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
         "icon_background_color":"#7B9EB0",
         "icon_mask_base_uri":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
         "name":"FERNANDO PELLET",
         "opening_hours":{
            "open_now":false
         },
         "photos":[
            {
               "height":304,
               "html_attributions":[
                  "<a href=""https"://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112336568147323955037">A Google User</a>"
               ],
               "photo_reference":"AWU5eFhAE9d8BzjyzK2__WL12xAhVmDVV9fe93T1isxXKhjXJklXXalO-j7RxwTDM7t0Jczdb_HyFuAXKS8szUozEj3UfvOL1Mkcsio-rY9R1pqAlZ6dKsnr2CcbPfalgsSpmu0VFpZhNMyo3B5e4VtPq0fW0oGapF9AvyH5lIO8ehPkqARv",
               "width":540
            }
         ],
         "place_id":"ChIJV8idBDN9EEcRjQKJVFPwQzA",
         "plus_code":{
            "compound_code":"489W+WX Uszyce, Poland",
            "global_code":"9F3W489W+WX"
         },
         "rating":4.7,
         "reference":"ChIJV8idBDN9EEcRjQKJVFPwQzA",
         "scope":"GOOGLE",
         "types":[
            "general_contractor",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total":15,
         "vicinity":"Uszyce 148"
      },
      {
         "business_status":"OPERATIONAL",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":51.01748689999999,
               "lng":18.0529209
            },
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":51.01873167989272,
                  "lng":18.05400282989272
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":51.01603202010728,
                  "lng":18.05130317010728
               }
            }
         },
         "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
         "icon_background_color":"#7B9EB0",
         "icon_mask_base_uri":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
         "name":"Hurtowa i detaliczna sprzedaż pelletu",
         "place_id":"ChIJ95MubZVoEEcRbC9fDNHUBkQ",
         "plus_code":{
            "compound_code":"2383+X5 Wołczyn, Poland",
            "global_code":"9F3W2383+X5"
         },
         "rating":0,
         "reference":"ChIJ95MubZVoEEcRbC9fDNHUBkQ",
         "scope":"GOOGLE",
         "types":[
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total":0,
         "vicinity":"Kluczborska 33, Wołczyn"
      },
      {
         "business_status":"OPERATIONAL",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":51.4537103,
               "lng":17.9860007
            },
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":51.45494492989273,
                  "lng":17.98741417989272
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":51.45224527010728,
                  "lng":17.98471452010728
               }
            }
         },
         "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
         "icon_background_color":"#7B9EB0",
         "icon_mask_base_uri":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet",
         "name":"Pelet D.G. - Producent Pelletu",
         "opening_hours":{
            "open_now":false
         },
         "photos":[
            {
               "height":1080,
               "html_attributions":[
                  "<a href=""https"://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108531728908816388599">A Google User</a>"
               ],
               "photo_reference":"AWU5eFjrXYEacesHLatZ0RRCRNOvUKGo1FdoSPsKwXIz4gcJoscReC__dMMOs1bP_yYHJhc3ROdB0wuzDXlV7UkdtpVTfsB7suHQ0rMEF8p5XvyFPSt7hlYavc6wsKUB0WrihZ9vOavJBh9cRdZiQnc_2VbJIABWekMF_hdQjqohXuqXVhHl",
               "width":1080
            }
         ],
         "place_id":"ChIJkTScEuuWGkcRsozUTO_9A-A",
         "plus_code":{
            "compound_code":"FX3P+FC Zajączki, Poland",
            "global_code":"9F3VFX3P+FC"
         },
         "rating":4.9,
         "reference":"ChIJkTScEuuWGkcRsozUTO_9A-A",
         "scope":"GOOGLE",
         "types":[
            "general_contractor",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total":15,
         "vicinity":"Zajączki 65A"
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```